# How to add Title in video by ffmpeg on Node JS

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I am working on a project where I have to add Title on a video by FFmpeg. I have already succeeded in adding a picture on a video. Can anybody help me to add Text(Title) on a video?

Here is my code for adding Image, please suggest the required modification:

```
    try {
        var process = new ffmpeg('public/'+req.body.video);
        process.then(function (video) {
          console.log('The video is ready to be processed');
          var watermarkPath = 'public/images/logo.png',
            newFilepath = 'public/videos/watermarked/'+name,
            settings = {
                position        : "SC"      // Position: NE NC NW SE SC SW C CE CW
              , margin_nord     : null      // Margin nord
              , margin_sud      : null      // Margin sud
              , margin_east     : null      // Margin east
              , margin_west     : null      // Margin west
            };
          var callback = function (error, files) {
            if(error){
              console.log('ERROR: ', error);
            }
            else{
              console.log('TERMINOU', files);
              res.send('videos/watermarked/'+name)
            }
          }
          //add watermark
          video.fnAddWatermark(watermarkPath, newFilepath, settings, callback)

        }, function (err) {
          console.log('Error: ' + err);
        });
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.code);
        console.log(e.msg);
      }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
command.videoFilters({
  filter: 'drawtext',
  options: {
    fontfile: 'Lucida Grande.ttf',
    text: 'THIS IS TEXT',
    /* etc. */
  }
});
```

Comment: @md-nazmul-hossain-bilash what is equivalent to `command` in the question? `process` maybe?

Comment: @md-nazmul-hossain-bilash I meant what is `command` in statement `command.videoFilters`?

Comment: ffmpeg('videos/input.mp4')
    .audioCodec('libmp3lame') // Audio Codec
    .videoCodec('libx264')  // Video Codec
    .videoFilters({
        filter: 'drawtext',
        options: {
            fontfile:'public/fonts/DINLight.ttf',
            text: "Bilash & Lopa",
            fontsize: 20,
            fontcolor: '#ccc',
            x: '(main_w/2-text_w/2)',
            y: 50,
            shadowcolor: 'black',
            shadowx: 2,
            shadowy: 2
        }
    })

Comment: @Bilash where did you find these options documented? Please share

Comment: Are they just from https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-drawtext-1?

Answer (score 2):

You can create canvas ,and add some text on canvas, and get png by canvas, and you can add Title in video by ffmpeg on Node JS.

[canvas](https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas)
[node-ffmpeg](https://github.com/damianociarla/node-ffmpeg)